# Python - How explicitly change evaluation of class object?

Tags: python, class, overloading

The function my_func gets one argument, that could be integer or a class:

```
class SomeClass:
    val = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
    def set(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def get(self):
        return self.val
```

and I want to work with both types as one. 
Can I somehow explicitly tell Python, that evaluation of an object of type  *SomeClass*, should return the *val* field of the object, but not the object it selves.

That means to get the following code work (somehow):

```
s = SomeClass()
s.set(3)
test = s # this line should assign value 3(int) to test
test # prints 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no, not in the broad sense that you seem to ask for.  You can overload many operations, not assignment. That's because variables are *just references to objects* and have no type attached. At any given time there can be many references to your object. It matters *how you use the object*, not what you assigned it to.

Instead, I'd make your class convertible to an integer. You can do so with the [`object.__int__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__); your setter would explicitly call `int()` on the object passed in:

```
class SomeClass:
    val = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
    def set(self, val):
        self.val = int(val)
    def get(self):
        return self.val 
    def __int__(self):
        return self.val
```

If you always use these objects in integer arithmetic, you could add hooks for those operations, such as [`object.__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [`object.__sub__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__sub__); again, it is the context in which the object is used that matters.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, it seems overriding __int__ method is what I need.

If my arg1 could be or integer or SomeClass object with implemented __int__ method, so if I do:

my_arg = int(arg1)

I'll get the integer value anyway and then I can operate with my_arg only.